# unable to access local file system from apache airflow python dag

Tags: airflow

I have a python function which reads data from local csv file. once i deployed the dag in airflow i am getting "No such file or directory" error.

i tried to set the env variable but no luck.

my code:

```
os.environ["EP"] = "/localpath/"
lp = os.environ["EP"]


def main():
print("Local Path", lp)
with open(lp + 'empty_csv.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')

  with DAG(
    dag_id="first_dag",
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    default_args={
        "owner": "airflow",
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
        "start_date": datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    },
    catchup=False) as f:



t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    python_callable=main,
    #dag=dag
)

t1
```

Comment: are you running airflow locally or on a docker container?

Is `print("Local Path", lp)`  output what you expected?

Comment: @pyeR_biz: i am using docker_compose. i am getting correct local mac path.[2021-07-09 18:09:24,126] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Local Path /Users/atc_admin/documents/AirFlow/
[2021-07-09 18:09:24,126] {{taskinstance.py:1128}} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/atc_admin/documents/AirFlow/empty_csv.csv'

Comment: if you're in a container, the container will have its own paths. Did you `COPY` or mount your data file inside the container. Before you go exploring that, try out navigating your container. 

`docker exec -it /bin/bash "your_webserver_container_name"` 

you can navigate your container's directories. if your data file is there somewhere, you have to use that path.

Comment: you might have already solved it. Just in case someone does not know, you need to map the local directories in docker-compose.yml file. Here's the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70749725/how-do-we-map-a-specific-local-directory-on-apache-airflow-docker-volumes.

Answer (score 4):

Add "- ./data:/opt/airflow/data" to volumes in docker-compose.yaml file, and use path as '/opt/airflow/data/posts.json'. This worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

try to test by placing the CSV in the same folder as your dag and then see of your code is working fine.
then,
I tried to create a folder inside the dag folder named- test
and gave the path as /usr/local/airflow/dags/test --> this worked since sometimes docker image identifies correctly /usr/local/airflow/