# How do we map a specific local directory on Apache Airflow Docker volumes?

Tags: docker, mapping, airflow, volume

Let's say, for example, I have a python script that I want to run as task A. It is located in C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Folder1\Script.py

I also want to move some csv files to C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Folder\CSVs through python script.

How do I map those 2 folders through volume? My compose.yaml currently looks like this:

volumes:
- ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
- ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
- ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins

When I try to indicate the local folder path as is, it's giving me "no such directory" error.

Answer (score 8):

Figured I have to indicate an absolute path to any local directory on Windows to map it on container.

For example if I need to use this folder C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Folder\CSVs, map it with the airflow container by modifying it in docker-compose.yaml, then compose up to apply changes

volumes:

- /c/Users/Name/Desktop/Folder/CSVs:/opt/airflow/CSVs