# Airflow directories, read a file in a task

Tags: directory, airflow

I've discovered Airflow recently and I want to do a couple of simple examples to know how it works.
So I've build a very simple DAG (example_airflow.py) like this

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import timedelta

def first_task(**kwargs):
    a = 1+1
    print(a)
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='val', value=a)

def second_task(ti):
    a = ti.xcom_pull(key='val', task_ids='first_task')
    b = a+a
    print(b)
    return b

default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',    
        'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    }

with DAG(dag_id="ejemplo_airflow",
        schedule_interval="@daily",
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup=False) as dag:
   

    first_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="first_task",
        python_callable=first_task,
        provide_context=True)

    second_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="second_task",
        python_callable=second_task,
        provide_context=True)

first_task >> second_task
```

When I run `docker-compose up` and go to localhost everything works perfectly, and the second task prints the value 4. Now I tried something like this

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import timedelta

def read_data(**kwargs):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_pickle("./dags/data/example.pkl")
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='df', value=df)

def first_task(ti):
    df = ti.xcom_pull(key='df', task_ids='read_data')
    x = df.shape
    print(x)
    return x

...

read_data >> first_task
```

And when I run `docker-compose up` it fails the task `read_data`. It says that 'No such file or directory' exists.

This is my structure:

```
├───home
│   ├───airflow
│   │   ├───example
│   │   ├──────dags
│   │   ├────────────example_airflow.py
│   │   ├────────────data
│   │   ├───────────────example.pkl
│   │   │──────logs
│   │   │──────plugins
│   │   ├───docker-compose.yaml
```

I'm running Airflow 2.3.2 in my local machine with Ubuntu 22.04. I tried to do a task with

```
def read_file(**kwargs):
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    AIRFLOW_HOME = os.getenv('AIRFLOW_HOME')
    file_df = pd.read_pickle(AIRFLOW_HOME + '/dags/data/example.pkl')
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='df', value=file_df)
```

and it doesn't work either. When I write a task like this

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

or with `AIRFLOW_HOME` it says that the directory is `/opt/***`.

Can someone explain to me how the directories work in Airflow or how should I do these kind of tasks?

Comment: could you try `pd.read_pickle("./dags/data/example.pkl")`?

Comment: @Emma it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

In the docker-compose you can see that your code volume is mapped :

```
`volumes:
  - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
  - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
  - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins`
```

so the path to data folder in your is relative to the volume mapping : ./dags/data

you can add data volume directly to your data folder

`- ./dags/data:/data`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. In my docker-compose I have this

  `volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/pt/airflow/plugins`
and the volumes within airflow-init is
`volumes:
- .:/sources`

Comment: When I run the command `docker exec -it airflow-worker_1 bash` it says `/opt/airflow`

Comment: Do you have./dags/data?

Comment: My folder structure is as I shown in the question. The directory `./dags/data` doesn't appear in the yaml

Comment: @Jero in your question you tried "./data/example.pkl" not "./dags/data/example.pkl". am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, sorry it was a typo in my question, I just edited, but I've tried with both routes and didn't work

Comment: @Jero, I can not reproduce your problem. I created a project same as you describe and it works fine. did you change anything in the docker-compose ?

Comment: @Jero, try the following workaround. add new volume ./dags/data:/data. now try to read from /data/example.pkl

Comment: It doesn't work either. My question is, where should I place my project folder? Let say I have my project in `/home/airflow/project`, should I change something in my yaml file? My docker-compose yaml is the one you get in the official web

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: @Jero, put the docker-compose under example and re-run it

Comment: Nothing happens. I'm reading this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70749725/how-do-we-map-a-specific-local-directory-on-apache-airflow-docker-volumes

and also reading the official airflow doc where it says: 
"The AIRFLOW_HOME is set by default to /opt/airflow/ - this means that DAGs are in default in the /opt/airflow/dags folder and logs are in the /opt/airflow/logs.
The working directory is /opt/airflow by default."
But I can't get a conclusion out of this. Should I always place my projects in /opt/ directory or just change the yaml to specify a different home?